# JQuery On Click Select Child Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, datatables, children

I have a datatables table that is also using the [row details api](http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html). This works just fine when I click on the `+` and `-` images.

However I want the details to show when the whole row is clicked, not just the `+` and `-` images.

Here is that section of the code:

```
$('#table tbody td img').on('click', function () {
    var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    if ( this.src.match('details_close') )
    {
        /* This row is already open - close it */
        this.src = "../images/details_open.png";
        oTable.fnClose( nTr );
    }
    else
    {
        /* Open this row */
        this.src = "../images/details_close.png";
        oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details' );
    }
});
```

I have tried removing the `img` from the first line of the code and doing `this.next('img').src` along with a few other variations, but all come back with errors saying that the match function won't work with them. How can I change the code so I can click on the whole row instead of just the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following changes should work:

```
$('#table tbody tr').on('click', function () {
   var nTr = this,
       img=$(this).find('td img')[0];
   if (img.src.match('details_close') )
    {
       /* This row is already open - close it */
       img.src = "../images/details_open.png";
       oTable.fnClose( nTr );
    }
   else
    {
       /* Open this row */
       img.src = "../images/details_close.png";
       oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details' );
    }
} );
```

The most likely reason you had issues with the `.match()` call is because you replaced the direct Node access with a jQuery object, and that does not have a match method.

Comment: Thanks, i tried this and im getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined".  tried var img = ... also. Any idea why that is?

Comment: @David You are making use of jQuery in your code right? because if you are using a diferent library the .find('img')[0] bit would not work as intended.

Comment: ya using jquery. Im thinking maybe its not finding the img in what you gave me because its in the same row as the td that im clicking? maybe i need to use tr or something

Comment: Yep, that was it! changed the first 3 lines to this:
`code`
$('#table tbody tr').on('click', function () {

var nTr = this;

var expandImg = $(this).find('td img')[0];

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
 $('#table tbody td').on('click', function () {
   var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
   if ( $('#table tbody td').src.match('details_close') )
    {
       /* This row is already open - close it */
       $('#table tbody td').src = "../images/details_open.png";
       oTable.fnClose( nTr );
    }
   else
    {
       /* Open this row */
       $('#table tbody td').src = "../images/details_close.png";
       oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details' );
    }
} );
```